# Can you override THIS keyword in JAVA

Tags: java, overriding, this, instance

Dealing with a refactoring scenario, and wondering if there's a way to override "this" in java.

Basically, I would like to return an instance of another class when this is called.

Is this possible?

Comment: No. `this` refers to the current `Object` instance. You could create an instance of your "other" class and make calls with `that`.

Comment: Would you really want to?

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to accomplish; this is almost certainly an XY question.

Comment: This was really an attempt at a shortcut refactoring a large class w/ heavy this.* usage. Essentially separation of concerns needs to be established and class needs to be broken up into 4-5 smaller classes. Coming from c# background was just wondering if java compiler would allow something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fundemental of java (and many others).   As stated in the comments the thing to do is create your 'that' class and return it.

Comment: I'm going to accept this as answer - as having this/that seems more elegant, and also the naming convention flows nicely with refactoring effort mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to override `this`. Create an instance of the desired class and return that instead.

```
Test t = new Test();
public Test getTest() {
    return this.t;
}
```